# Extracting specific value from a variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose Variable name="var" is having this below XML

```
<a>
  <b>
    <bb>234</bb>
  </b>
  <c>345</c>
  <d>456</d>
</a>
```

How Can only access bb inside var? something like *value-of select="**$var/a/b/bb***".

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below xslt to get `bb` value

XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="sample" select="/" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sample/*/*/*"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

`234`